# MyBatis Select Query

Tags: mybatis

Assume I have a db table with two columns: first_name and last_name with 50 rows and I have created all the mappings in MyBatis

```
 @Select("SELECT * FROM users")
@Results({
    @Result(property = "firstName", column = "first_name"),
    @Result(property = "lastName", column = "last_name")
})
List<User> findUsers();
```

Now, if I want to get the 5th name from the first_name column, how do I iterate the List and get that.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, once you have the list of user it is easy.

```
List<User> users = myService.findUsers();

String my5thName = users.get(4).getFirstName();
```

Did I understand well your question?

Comment: Thanks jddsantaella What is myService in the above example?

Comment: The class where you have the `findUsers` method. Before use it, you need to instantiate it.

Comment: I am sorry jddsantaella, I got the above code from a forum. My basic question was what needs to go inside findUsers method. All I am trying to do is, throw the query output to a list and then iterate through it. Sorry for any inconvenience and confusions

Comment: Well. You cannot go inside the method because you are dealing with an interface. The interface and its methods will be implemented by myBatis (you do not need to care about how). MyBatis will provide you the list of users and then you can do it with it whatever you want, as iterate through it.